# Possible to obtain netinet/in.h using gnulib-tool?

Tags: linux, windows, mingw, mingw-w64, gnulib

I sort of ended up in the same problem as [Getting started with gnulib on MinGW and not familiar (enough) with autotools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060183/getting-started-with-gnulib-on-mingw-and-not-familiar-enough-with-autotools) - that is, wanting to include headers like `netinet/in.h` in a MinGW Windows project; and that is where I first heard of `gnulib`.

As the above post notes, the primary intention of `gnulib` is to sort of "patch" an existing `autoconf` project with the right files; however I work with a project whose build system I don't really understand - so at first, I thought of just copying headers.

Now, I'm not really sure, but it seems to me as if `gnulib` will generate these headers based on the system it is ran on - which is why instead of containing `netinet/in.h` verbatim, it in fact contains:

```
gnulib_git$ find . -name '*.h' | grep netinet
./lib/netinet_in.in.h
```

Indeed, this file has stuff like `@PRAGMA_SYSTEM_HEADER@`, which I can only assume are some macros.

So, I found there is a command `--create-testdir`, so I tried it like this:

```
rm -rf /tmp/AA # erase previous, else it won't run
./gnulib-tool --create-testdir --dir=/tmp/AA getsockname getsockopt setsockopt socket socketlib sockets socklen sys_socket arpa_inet inet_ntop inet_pton netinet_in
cd /tmp/AA
./configure
make
```

I've tried this on Linux, it runs fine, however:

```
$ find /tmp/AA -name '*.h' | grep netinet
/tmp/AA/gllib/netinet_in.in.h
```

... I still don't get any headers verbatim (and that one still has macros inside)? Turns out I cannot try this on my MinGW-w64, as there is no `aclocal` program there...

So could anyone explain whether full headers can ever be generated using `--create-testdir`, or how/when in the process can one expect to obtain the actual headers (and whether it is host OS dependent)?

Answer (score 0):

gnulib will not create a `netinet/in.h` file of its own when it finds that the system's include file of the same name is fully functional - which is fortunately the case on glibc systems.

But on other platforms, like mingw, there likely will be a `netinet/in.h` file created by gnulib, and it will reference the system's include file of the same name. Yes, `@PRAGMA_SYSTEM_HEADER@` is part of the macrology that makes this possible.

You don't need to have the Autotools on the target system (here: mingw). The idea of the GNU build system is that you create `configure`, `Makefile.in`, and `config.h` files on a machine with the Autotools. Then you can transport the resulting package to the target machine. On the target machine, per [GNU standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Utilities-in-Makefiles), you only need the basic shell utilities (such as coreutils, sed, gawk).